# Fictitious play for Matching Pennies (zero-sum game)

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am trying for an exercise to use `Fictitious Play` to find a mixed Nash equilibrium for the Matching Pennies zero-sum game with matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

According to Fictitious play, the row and column player update their strategies in step $t$ according to the following formula:

$$x^t = \frac{1}{t} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^t e_{i,t}^m$$
$$y^t = \frac{1}{t} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^t e_{j,t}^n$$

Where $e_{i,t}^m$ is a $m$-dimensional unit base vector (= pure strategy). In this case, A is quadratic so $m = n$.

Now in class we said that $x^0 = y^0 = 0^n$ (zero-vector).
According to me trying to solve the exercise, this initialisation doesn't make much sense because `Fictitious Play` is going to converge after 2 steps:

Choose $x^0 = y^0 = 0^n$ such that both players can select a random pure strategy in step $t=1$, e.g. $e_{i,1} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $e_{j,1} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ such that $x^1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $y^1 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Then if we calculate the best response for $e_{i,2}$:

$$x^TAy^1 \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

and $e_{j,2}$

$$(x^1)^TAy \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

So we end up with:

$$x^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$y^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}$$

Which already is the Nash equilibrium.

Did I get something wrong about `Fictitious Play`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^2$ is wrong in what you wrote above:

You started with (Heads, Tails), that is Heads for player 1 and Tails for player 2. Then, in the next round, player 1 wants to match Tails, and player 2 wants to mismatch Heads, so the next pure strategy profile is (Tails, Tails).

Comment: Could you explain then how the update formula works?

Comment: You extend the sequences of pure strategies with pure best responses to $x^t$ and $y^t$. Your formulas for $x^t$ and $y^t$ look fine. What you did wrong was computing the best response of player 2 to $x^1$: Since $x^1$ is row 1, player 2's best response to $x^1$ is column 2, not column 1.

Comment: But wouldn't the players trying to maximise $x^TAy$?

Comment: Matching Pennies is a zero-sum game. A is the payoff matrix for player 1. B, the payoff matrix for player 2 is equal to -A. It is normal to just write everything in terms of payoff matrix A, where then player 1 maximises (these payoffs) and player 2 minimises (these costs). Note, that if A=B, as you had in mind, then the game always has at least one *pure* equilibrium (any maximum entry of A).

Comment: Thanks! This cleared things up for me